# Can't show products in Magento 1.8

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, product

I can't show products in my site that I added in admin page (even if I use the product URL manually it always redirects me the homepage).

example : I had a product phone in the category hightech when I open the hightech submenu in my website I didn't find it (it was working perfectly before and I don't know what causes this problem)

I tried to refresh cache and reindex data but always the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to check some information bellow:

- **Product Inventory**: Is it "in stock" or "out of stock". Only in stock product can be show in frontend
- **Product Status**: Enabled or Disabled?
- **Visibilily**: "Catalog, Search", ....
- Did you add product to Websites? (Using Websites tab in Product editing page)

Comment: The products are in stock, enabled and visible (the products showed in the category menu but as out of stock and when I open anyone is redirects me to the homepage)

Comment: Did you try to reindex all data again?